# RewriteCond HTTP_REFERER to allow own site as url parameters and block other url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I want to receive own site's url as $_GET parameter in few of my pages but don't want any other url to pass as $_GET parameter on any webpages. For this the .htaccess code with few other measures mentioned here.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(&#x22;|&#x27;|&#x3C;|&#x3E;|&#x5C;|&#x7B;|&#x7C;).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|select|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite\.com(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

</IfModule>
```

Even after adding

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite\.com(.*)$
```

at the 3rd line from end, if I try to pass any url of my website as GET parameter in any of my webpages like including http `(ex: 'http://mysite\.com')`, it returns 403 error.

Here is the way I am trying to access my site's url as GET parameter:

`'http://mysite\.com/abc_page?url=http://mysite\.com/efg_page'`

Please point me what I am doing wrong with the above code. The code was actually added by Word Press Better Security Plugin and I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite\.com(.*)$` to allow url of my own website.

'\' added before .com because stackoverflow does not allow to use mysite.com name to place inside body.